# Checks on foreign key of foreign key in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have these 3 sql alchemy (sqla) models:

```
class Site(Base):
    __tablename__ = "site"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True, default=datetime.utcnow(), onupdate=datetime.utcnow)


class Camera(Base):
    __tablename__ = "camera"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    site_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("site.id"), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True, default=datetime.utcnow(), onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
    site = relationship("Site", backref="cameras")


class RtspServerEndpoint(Base):
    __tablename__ = "rtsp_server_endpoint"
    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    camera_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey("camera.id"), nullable=False)
    rtsp_url_endpoint = Column(String, nullable=False)
    rtsp_username = Column(String, nullable=False)
    rtsp_encrypted_password = Column(String, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=True, default=datetime.utcnow(), onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
    camera = relationship("Camera", backref="rtsp_server_endpoint", lazy="joined")
```

`camera_id` is the foreign key of `rtspserverendpoint` table and `site_id` is the foreign key for the Camera table.

When a user wants to add a new `rtspserverendpoint` record, he makes an HTTP request such as:
POST sites/<site_id>/camera/<camera_id>/rtspserverendpoint

Before adding the new `rtspserverendpoint`, I would like to make sure that the `<site_id>` and the `<camera_id>` are consistent, as a security. I can probably make a separate query just to check that, such as:

```
check_record_exist = db.session.query(Camera).filter(Camera.site_id == site_id).first()
if not check_record_exist:
    raise ("No such camera with this site_id")
```

But what I would like to know, is if there is a more elegant way to check that: For example, adding a constraint in my Base models that would forbid adding such an inconsistent record in the database.

Comment: `ForeignKey` *is* the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any straightforward way to implement this 2-level check on the database directly.

In fact, the only consistency that the database should know about is that your new `RtspServerEndpoint` instance will belong to the correct `Camera` instance. But this will be correct by default by the way you will be creating the `RtspServerEndpoint` instance.

Therefore, in my opinion, the check of the correctness of the `site_id` in the URL of the POST request should be implemented in the logic of your code. I would probably do it along these lines:

```
@handler(..., method='POST')
def rtspserverendpoint(site_id: int, camera_id: int):
    # find camera, which will allow us to check the correctness of the site_id as well
    camera = db.session.query(Camera).get(camera_id)

    if camera is None:
        raise Exception(f"No camera with this {camera_id=}.")

    if camera.site_id != site_id:
        raise Exception(f"Camera with this {camera_id=} does not belong to the site with {site_id=}.")

    new_obj = RtspServerEndpoint(
        ...,
        camera_id=camera_id,
        ...,
    )

    db.session.add(new_obj)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's actually what I want to do, except that I would get the camera with both filters on camera_id and site_id. 

Then, if camera is None, it means there is an inconsistensy between camera_id and site_id

Comment: I am not sure you statement is correct about the "inconsistency". Because you will also get `None` when Camera with the id of `camera_id` does not exist at all. So checking those two conditions separately is more robust.